# Twilio, Chat client initialization failed with: Request to EMS service has failed, unable to set FPA token}

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

If I generate an access token with voice and chat grants, I can not build a chat client it returns "Request to EMS service has failed, unable to set FPA token". Access token with only chat grant works as expected. I've checked all Twilio service SID's, API keys etc..

Here example of my token generation method:

```
 var grants = new HashSet<IGrant>
        {
            new VoiceGrant()
            {
                OutgoingApplicationSid = voiceSid,
                PushCredentialSid = pushCreds
            },
            new ChatGrant()
            {
                ServiceSid = chatSid,
                PushCredentialSid = pushCreds,
                EndpointId = $"chatSample_{identity}"
            },

        };


        var token = new Token(
            accSid,
            apiKey,
            apiSecret,
            identity,
            grants: grants);

return token.ToJwt();
```

Comment: Can you post an example of an JWT that this creates? I'd like to inspect the result of this code. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @philnash, sure: I can't post too long post so  I share it, see my link https://www.dropbox.com/s/1d98qob2oq0x8u0/token%20example.txt?dl=0
I masked all my credentials values with "XXX"

Comment: Hmm... Today it is working fine, looks like it was a Twilio issue. Could it be?

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid. Hard to tell what was happening.